# Extract Enterprise app's IPA in iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

As you know, Apple disabled app extraction in iOS 9. But in this case I'm talking about an enterprise app not bought apps from App Store.

Is there anyway to backup or better to say extract IPA of installed apps in an iOS 9 device?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple remove this feature for various reasons. See: 
[Why did Apple kill App extraction in iOS 9?](https://imazing.com/blog/why-did-apple-kill-app-extraction-in-ios-9)

> 3 very good reasons which we believe pushed Apple to completely remove app extraction from iOS 9:
>
> 1. App Slicing
>
> Because universal apps are destined to be stripped, extracting the .ipa package from an iOS 9 device doesn’t make much sense anymore: it may only be installable on a device with identical resolution.
>
> 2. Frequent Updates Improve Security
>
> Blocking app extraction will effectively shorten the lifespan of stale versions of apps, improving overall security of the iOS ecosystem.
>
> 3. Preserve Disk Use
>
> All these backed up apps quickly add up, and can result in literally tens of gigabytes of outdated apps eating up your precious hard drive space.

If you'd like to have a backup of your app, you can try to use [iMazing app](https://imazing.com/blog/imazing-1-3-app-back-uprestore) for backing up and restoring application data.